# Почему вылетает ошибка undeclared identifier Delphi

Tags: delphi

Не могу использовать процедуры, написанные в другом модуле Delphi, хотя в implementation указано соответствующее uses. Директива {$R *.dfm} тоже на месте. Вылетаетс ошибка E2003 undeclared identifier

Comment: А в interface секцию вынесено?

Comment: @KoVadim Вы имеете в виду вынести uses Unit1? А зачем? Да и проблему это никак не решает, все та же ошибка. Могу кинуть сюда код модуля

Comment: нет. у любого юнита есть две основные секции - interface и implementation. То, что в первой секции - это "публичная часть", доступная тем, кто через uses использует этот модуль. вторая секция - это приватная часть. Другим недоступна.

Comment: @KoVadim Вы были правы, спасибо, вопрос решен

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. в библиотечном модуле перечисляем все функции в interface. Сохраняем (как пример) MyLib.pas
2. в программе в interface uses ставим название библиотечного модуля (рядом с Windows, Classes,  Forms). Как пример uses Windows, Classes,  Forms, MyLib

Есть еще вариант вида: uses UnitForm in 'UnitForm.pas'